# registerClientScriptBlock in custom handler?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, page-lifecycle

I'm using a custom control in ASP.NET that handles file uploading for me. The control has a handler in the code-behind using something like this:

```
Protected Sub UploadFileComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs) Handles UploadControl.FileUploadComplete
```

Within that sub, I post back to the server and do some work on the database, but then when I come back, I want JavaScript to register at that point.

However, when I use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` or `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`, the scripts don't load on the page. I need this JavaScript to run and update the page, and to close the upload dialog window. I assume it's because the page is already loaded.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so turns out it's like this...

On the server side (code-behind), in the `UploadFileComplete()` sub, you can access that `EventArgs` variable by using the method `e.CallbackData = [WHATEVER]`.

And then in your javascript, you use this built in client function:

```
function UploadComplete(args){
    alert(args.callbackData);
}
```

And that `args.callbackData` variable has whatever you put in via server side. Pretty slick I think! But hard to figure out cause they didn't have it documented very well.

This way, you don't need to add your own `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method, because you can pass in anything you want to JavaScript using their built in method.